# can anyone identify this plant please?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can anyone tell me what the potted plant is, circled on the right?
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: It looks artificial, whatever it is supposed to be...

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a plastic plant pretending to be a geranium. There's a large variety in geraniums, but at least some have the combination of variegated leaves and pink flowers. In addition, the leaf shape is about right, and geraniums form those flower clumps at the end of stems as well. The photo is of the "Little Dandy" variety of geranium

[image]

Comment: Probably polyethylene or polypropylene.